# How to input specific character to a TextField with the click of the Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I implemented on a TextField that can display mention suggestions by typing `@`, just like in Slack.

However, users don't noticed that there is a Mention feature.
So I'm thinking of creating an `@` button so that when the button is clicked, the list can be displayed just like when typing `@`.

In order to implement the Mentions feature, It use a `react-mentions` package.
`react-mentions` will show a list of mentions when a matching `trigger` is entered, by passing the `trriger: string` props.
I have passed `trigger="@"` to `react-mentions`.

So, it is not enough to add `@` to the TextField when the `@` button is clicked.
The same event needs to happen on the web as when I type `@` from the keyboard.

Is it possible to achieve such a thing with JavaScript?

Thank you.

Comment: It would help people help you if you did a Stack Snippet (the `[<>]` toolbar button) with a minimal example of your use of `react-mentions`. Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Try triggering the `keypress` or `keydown` event on the TextField.